# app to make shortcuts that will type words

Tags: windows, macros, hotkeys

is there some software for windows that will allow me to register a shortcut that will type a certain sentence

for example the app runs and when I'm in word/skype/browser and I type Ctrl+Shift+G

it will type "good morning"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a great solution for this :
http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php

You can create Shortcut for writing text, lauching apps, etc.

It's Free & OpenSource :)

NB: Website is only in french, but software is in english (or french)